# Where did the lock screen ring go to with Lollipop, and how to get it back?

Tags: lock-screens

Up to Android Kitkat, there was the lock screen ring:

[image: Lock screen ring]
<sup>Lock screen with activated unlock ring</sup>

One could define up to 4 apps to be directly started from here (plus the option to simply unlock). This seems to have changed with Lollipop: there's only the phone symbol in the lower-left and the camera icon in the lower-right corner which one might redefine. When I discovered that on my first LP device I thought it might be due to the specific ROM (CyanogenOS 12.1) – but after having another device updated to Lollipop, I see it's the same thing there.

Two shortcuts are simply not enough for me – so I ask myself whether I've missed something (e.g. didn't find the corresponding setting), or if it's really gone for good. I want the ring back – so how to achieve that? Two possibilities which are not a real option: third-party lock screen apps (which usually want access to a bunch of things to work properly), or the *Gravity Box* XPosed module (doesn't work with CyanogenMod: device becomes unstable and behaves weird).

Comment: Pretty sure it's just gone, because they decided to change the whole lockscreen to be a giant notification area. Your options outside of third-party stuff are probably pretty limited, if any exist at all.

Comment: Thanks @eldarerathis – I was afraid of that. And exactly that notification stuff is the second thing I strongly dislike, wanting it back the way it was in Kitkat and before. I tried some 3rd party tools, but up to now all failed: with GravityBox the device didn't even start up cleanly, using a 3rd party lockscreen app caused the device to freeze every night. Quite disappointing. Just wonder that nobody complained about this before (I did a quick search before posting), or I must have missed it. Also miss weather and next appointments on lock screen …